# deleting rows if matching partial string in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, row, openpyxl

I am trying to delete every row containing a partial string. It is correctly identifying the correct rows containing the partial string, it is just not deleting them from the sheet.

Here is my attempt:

````
for row in sheet10.iter_rows(2,sheet.max_row-1):
    message = row[10].value
    if  message != None and 'My partial string' in message:
        print(row[10].value)
        print(row[0].row)
        sheet10.delete_rows(row[0].row, 1)
        ```
````

Comment: This code is incomplete.

Comment: Just noticed that the ``` characters were the culprit , they cut off the first line. sorry about that @CharlieClark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but anyways, here is an example for the general logic :

```
wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")

ws = wb.active

rows_to_delete = [
    row[0].row for row in ws.iter_rows()
    if any("foo" in str(cell.value) for cell in row)
] # [2, 3, 5]

for row_idx in reversed(rows_to_delete): #to avoid the index from shifting-up
    ws.delete_rows(row_idx)

wb.save("new_file.xlsx")
```

Or, as suggested by @[*Charlie Clark*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385133/charlie-clark), for more readability, you can construct the indexes this way :

```
rows_to_delete = [
    idx for idx, row in enumerate(
        ws.iter_rows(values_only=True), start=1) #or ws.values
    if any(isinstance(cell, str) and "foo" in cell for cell in row)
]  # [2, 3, 5]
```

Another variant :

```
rows_to_delete = []

for idx, row in enumerate(ws.values, start=1):
    check = any(isinstance(value, str) and "foo" in value for value in row)
    if check:
        rows_to_delete.append(idx)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: FWIW `for row in sheet:` would also work here though I'd personally be tempted to use `values_only=True / ws.values` with an enumerator because it makes the comprehension easier to read and `isinstance(v, str)` to avoid casting.

```rows_to_delete = []
for idx, row in enumerate(ws.values, start=1):
     check = any(value for values in row if isinstance(value, str) and "foo" in value)
     if check rows_to_delete.append(idx)```

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark, that's fair enough, the format of the listcomp you proposed, is more readable. I updated my answer accordingly ;) –

Comment: I personally find nested comprehensions really difficult to debug. My hunch is that avoiding casting and short-circuiting with any() will make this fast even on the biggest sheet. Actually, delete_rows() is going to be the bottleneck here. I've thought about adding support for lists of rows to make it singlepass…

Comment: I agree about the nested *listcomps*. I often find them a bit of a headache too. But although they can be tricky to debug, I've gotten used using them! Anyways, looking forward the support of lists of rows, that would be cool ;)